# How to attach an image with sms without showing Action chosser in android?

Tags: android, action, send

I have to attach an image file with the sms on button click i use this code

```
final Intent smsIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "Hello World!"); 
smsIntent.putExtra("address", "0123456789");
smsIntent.putExtra(Intent.ACTION_ATTACH_DATA,screenshotUri);
smsIntent.setType("image/png");
startActivity(smsIntent);
```

But this shows a chooser to choose an action like Facebook,Email,Messages etc.
But i do not want any the chosser view it will directly show the message intent with attached file.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for cannot be done using `implicit` Intents. Because that is how the Android system is designed to handle implicit intents. If you want your intent to be handled by a specific application then you have to make them `explicit`, i.e., specify a component that has to handle the intent. But when you use `explicit` intents to handle any situation such as yours, then there is a great chance of your app to break when the specific component (i.e. Application) doesn't not exist in the target device. Android is being adopted by several OEMs, therefore each of them tend to replace the stock Messaging application with their own. So what seems to work on one device may not work on the other.

If you want to achieve what you want then you may have to get the list of Messaging applications on various devices, (you can find the stock Android app's component name from the emulator itself). And use the `PackageManager` to find if the component exists. If it does, the start and `explicit` intent, in which you won't receive an `IntentChooser`. If the component doesn't exist send an `implicit` intent.

You can learn more about intents from [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html).

[Determining if an Activity exists on the current device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2878694/determining-if-an-activity-exists-on-the-current-device/2879403#2879403) - This post will help you to find if the target component exists.

Comment: I had already gothrough all these links but it doesn't help me more. Do you know waht i am asking in my question i have to show message intent with attaches file without showing the prompt.

Comment: I assume, you want to use the default SMS / Email application? Is that correct?

Comment: Do we set Message Intent(from the others) as default intent on Action_Send progamatically.

Comment: Use `intent.setComponent()`, but this is still difficult because you need to know what extras are being supported by your target component.