# Unsupported action error on click of email link

Tags: android

I have given email link to TextView in xml, but as I am clicking on the TextView its showing unsupported action error, How can I put the active link on email in textview?

Here is my code of string.xml file:

```
     <resources>
           <string name="emailLink"><a href="mailto:info@knowledgewoods.in">info@knowledgewoods.in</a></string>
     <resources>
```

And mylayout.xml

```
      <TextView 
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:textSize="15dp"
         android:textColor="@color/text_color"
         android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
         android:id="@+id/text_email"
         android:autoLink="email"
         android:text="@string/emailLink"/>
```

I am running my app in android 2.2 and later versions.

Please help me...
Thanks

Comment: Do you have any email application installed in your device.?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is likely to occur when you haven't added a primary account to your mobile. You have to configure your google account with your device. Go to the gmail app in your device and sign in using your gmail account. I had the same problem and after doing this the problem was solved.

Comment: Is there a way to handle this error programmatically and throw a toast to the user "please setUp your email account" instead of showing him the  Unsupported Action error ?

Comment: @sakiskaliakoudas This is probably what you want to do: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2879403/15139

Comment: @rpattabi, I tried this and found that it actually still returns a single result: `com.android.fallback.FallbackActivity`.

Answer (score 2):

From my testing, this is a problem that happens when the intent's URI (from `setData()`) doesn't match anything and you're running on one of the official Android emulators. This doesn't seem to happen on real devices, so it shouldn't be a real-world problem.