# Determine the various SDKs an Android user has installed on their phone

Tags: android, google-app-engine, mobile, sdk, analytics

There are many apps coming out (and already out) that use various analytics SDKs that utilize the apps' permissions to gather data about the user.

Is it possible to determine the various SDKs that are currently installed / active on a user's phone?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it's not that simple, because most of the tools is just compiled into the app. You can check several obvious places for known SDK signatures. For example:

- check intents available to call (see: [Determining if an Activity exists on the current device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2878694/determining-if-an-activity-exists-on-the-current-device))
- scan logcat output for logs (for example: '%Initializing Crashlytics%' for Crashlytics)
- check for folders containing any SDK-specific data

In general I would start with a research, how the SDKs work.

Comment: Got it! The ones I know are being quite sneaky but ultimately it should show up in the logs. Will look.