# Android - Is it possible to determine if it is able to go to another activity without goging to it?

Tags: android, android-activity

we have got problem with our android application.
We want to determine if it will not crash when we go to another activity, but we do not want to go there, just check if it will be possible or not...

Thank you,

Comment: "We want to determine if it will not crash when we go to another activity" so you want to predict the future? afaik it is not possible in the real life...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determining if an Activity exists on the current device?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2878694/determining-if-an-activity-exists-on-the-current-device)

Comment: let me update question :) i want to open activity but NOT OPEN like it will be visible, just something like open in iframe or only emulate open of that activity...

Comment: Why do you want to do that? You could possibly finish the activity(which you want to test) in your onCreate or bring the old Activity back to foreground.

Comment: imagine situation...

i am in activity B and i want to go back to activity A, but after i go back to activity A it crash... I want to restart app when ii am in activity B, not after i go back to A :) so thats why i want some workaround to determine if activity A is working before i go there...

Comment: tried `Thread#setUncaughtExceptionHandler` / `Thread#setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler` ?

Comment: You can check if an activity is running by using the ActivityManager. Also you can Intent Flag to force the Activity to be recreated.

Comment: you could fix what's crashing, which would be a nicer approach.