# Checking existence of an Activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I am considering the code in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2878694/determining-if-an-activity-exists-on-the-current-device/2879403#2879403), and did the following:

First, I create a simple, empty project with only one `Activity` called `MainActivity`, which is in package `com.example.plugins`. I compile this project and install it to my device. The app works fine.

Then, in another project I have this code:

```
Intent plugins = new Intent();
plugins.setClassName("com.example.plugins", "MainActivity");
List<ResolveInfo> list = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(plugins,
                PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
if (list.size() > 0) {
    tvText.setText("Plugins.");
} else {
    tvText.setText("No Plugins.");
}
```

I'd say this should work, but it doesn't. It gives "no plugins". Am I missing something here?

**Update** When using

```
PackageInfo pi = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                    "com.example.plugins", PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
```

I do get the activities from that other app.

Comment: so you need to know is package installed or not, right?

Comment: @DEADMC, that and I want to call the activity to get some info out of it. I am experimenting to create some kind of plugin system (as for example DDLs in C#)

Answer (score 0):

I think the MIME-type of the Intent is missing.

```
plugins.setType("text/plain");
```

Comment: This doesn't have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

When setting the class name, you have to use the complete name, including package:

```
plugins.setClassName("com.example.plugins", "com.example.plugins.MainActivity");
```